Initiate by signing Solana Transaction through EVM provider
The purpose of this is to send transaction on solana network by signing it from EVM provider.
We have user's wallet which has Ethereum Provider, Ethers Provider or Web3 Provider.
The code is given below.
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
    const sender = new PublicKey("8Jd3Y6t7LkKjK1EcCx1gAqGwYGjT8MKuT7w2xmcMC8Cu");
    const receiver = new PublicKey('2F9Kx5nckQ7ya49o6PZEoqx2f91jcrSNpmuHnfoGRr4P');
    const amount = 1000000;
    let transaction = new Transaction().add(
      SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: sender,
        toPubkey: receiver,
        lamports: amount,
      })
    );

    const eip712Domain = [
      { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
      { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' }
    ];

    const solanaTransfer = [
      { name: 'sender', type: 'address' },
      { name: 'receiver', type: 'address' },
      { name: 'amount', type: 'uint256' },
      { name: 'solanaTransaction', type: 'bytes' }
    ];
    const blockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed");
    transaction.recentBlockhash = blockHash.blockhash;
    transaction.feePayer = sender;
    const serializedTransaction = transaction.serializeMessage();

    const eip712Data = {
      types: {
        EIP712Domain: eip712Domain,
        SolanaTransfer: solanaTransfer,
      },
      domain: {
        name: "Solana to EVM",
        version: "1",
        chainId: 97, // BSC Testnet
        verifyingContract: "0x6a17767c93D2081584E11025d555b4D9586dFE73",
      },
      primaryType: 'SolanaTransfer',
      message: {
        sender: sender.toString(),
        receiver: receiver.toString(),
        amount: amount,
        solanaTransaction: '0x' + serializedTransaction,
      },
    };
    let signature;
    if (walletProvider) {
      signature = await walletProvider.request({
        method: "eth_signTypedData_v4",
        params: [evmAddress, eip712Data],
      });
    }

const solanaSignature = convertSignature(signature);
    // const solanaSignature = Buffer.from(signature, 'hex');
    transaction.addSignature(sender, Buffer.from(solanaSignature));

    const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize({ verifySignatures: false });
    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction);
    console.log('Transaction ID:', txid);


The problem in the above code snippet is that when i sign the EVM Eip712 and convert its signature from EVM to SOLANA, then while broadcasting it says invalid signature for public key.
function convertSignature(signature: string) {
  const sigBytes = ethers.utils.arrayify(signature);
  return sigBytes.slice(0, 64);
}```


Solana uses a different signature scheme than Ethereum, so you cannot use an Ethereum signature as one of the transaction signatures in a Solana transaction.
You'll need to generate an Ed25519 signature to use it with Solana. If you want to validate an Ethereum signature, you can pass the signature as instruction data and use the secp256k1 program to validate it https://docs.solanalabs.com/runtime/programs#secp256k1-program, but then it becomes an application-specific issue.
